# Combining Fineract on backend and mifos UI on front end

Tags: web-applications, mifos

I have successfully installed fineract platform on my windows system.
The local host is working perfectly fine.
How can i design an User interface for the fineract platform same as mifos x.

I tried dropping mifos UI file to fineract platform.But it is showing some error.

If it is not possible.
how can i design UI for my Fineract platform which handles banking services?

Thanks!

Designing a microfinance service by using fineract platform as an backend.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Fineract 1.X and running it in a Tomcat container, then do the following:

1. Get access to the **built** UI app folder. It will have a name *community-app* or *web-app* depending on whether you are using the legacy app or the newest one that is still in development.
2. Copy the folder into /pathToTomcat/webapps/
3. Rename the folder /pathToTomcat/webapps/ROOT to /pathToTomcat/webapps/OLDROOT
4. Rename the folder you copied in step 1 to ROOT and restart tomcat
5. You should now be able to access the UI at https(s)://IP ADDRESS//
6. If you are using a self-signed certificate in tomcat, then you will need to accept the security warnings about the same in the browser.
7. If you want to develop your own UI, the have a look at the api documentation https://demo.fineract.dev/fineract-provider/api-docs/apiLive.htm

Answer (score 0):

Simply, You can fetch Community App from GitHub then install nodejs Version 10.18.0, Ruby Version 2.7.6 and follow these instructions:
1.git clone https://github.com/openMF/community-app
2.npm install -g bower
3.npm install -g grunt-cli
4.bower install
5.npm install
6.gem install bundler
7.bundle install
8.grunt serve

I try the above solution to run the Mifos community-app on Linux Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Fineract 1.X is an open source headless banking solution.
To use it you have 3 options:

1. Use the community open source project

There are opensource community solutions that work with Fineract 1.X for example https://github.com/openMF/web-app.

2. Develop your own UI

Fineract uses REST apis to communicate with the front end. So you create your own front end solution to work with the backend.

3. Use a premium front end.

BANKAYO is a UI built for Fineract,it is customizable and can be used on a wide device range laptops, tablets and phones. You have a look at it here https://bankayo.io